# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException TreeMap

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dacia.Principale.jButton10ActionPerformed(Principale.java:1204)
    at dacia.Principale.access$500(Principale.java:44)
```

Code:

```
   XSSFWorkbook wg= new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sht=wg.createSheet();

    TreeMap<String,Object[]> data= new TreeMap<>();
  //  data.put("-1",new Object[]){"chasis","marque","couleur","nom client","date d entree","date sortie","telephone","numero WW","position","mode paiment","gamme","version"});
    data.put("-1",new Object[]{jTable2.getColumnName(0),jTable2.getColumnName(1),jTable2.getColumnName(2),jTable2.getColumnName(3),jTable2.getColumnName(4),jTable2.getColumnName(5),jTable2.getColumnName(6),jTable2.getColumnName(7),jTable2.getColumnName(8),jTable2.getColumnName(9),jTable2.getColumnName(10),jTable2.getColumnName(11)});

    for(int i=0;i<jTable2.getRowCount();i++)
   {

       data.put(Integer.toString(i),new Object[]{jTable2.getValueAt(i,0).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,1).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,2).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,3).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,4).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,5).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,6).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,7).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,8).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,9).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,10).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,11).toString()});
   }
   //write to excel
   Set <String> ids=data.keySet();
   XSSFRow row ;
   int roow=0 ;
   for (String st : ids)
   {
       row=sht.createRow(roow++);
       Object[] values=data.get(st);
       int cellId=0 ;
       for(Object o : values)
       {
           Cell cell=row.createCell(cellId++);
           cell.setCellValue(o.toString());

       }
   }
    try {
        //write to file
        FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/elprincipe/Desktop/dacia.xls"));
        wg.write(fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Principale.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Principale.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The problem is in:

```
   data.put(Integer.toString(i),new Object[]{jTable2.getValueAt(i,0).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,1).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,2).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,3).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,4).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,5).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,6).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,7).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,8).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,9).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,10).toString(),jTable2.getValueAt(i,11).toString()});
```

Comment: Most likely one of the cells returns `null` and you can't call `.toString()` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell by your code, something in your `jTable2` is not getting initialized properly.

The idea of a [`NullPointerException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) is that you are trying to use an object that hasn't been created yet. Since you are able to iterate over the `jTable2`, and you don't have an index out of bounds exception, I would say that one of the elements of the `jTable2` is not being created

What I would suggest is going over this in the debugger, carefully analyzing each row of the table before you try to convert it to a `String`

---

Also, (this is more of a style thing, but I think it'll help you in the long run) you should move this sort of functionality into another method, so that it'll be easier to read:

```
for(int i = 0; i < jTable2.getRowCount(); i++) {
    data.put(convertRow(jTable2, i));
}

public Object[] convertRow(Table jTable2, int row) {
    rowLength = jTable2[0].length;
    Object[] row = new Object[rowLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
        Object datum = jTable2.getValueAt(row, i);
        if (datum != null) {
            row[i] = datum.toString();
        }
        else {
            row[i] = "Null entry"
        }
    }

    return row         
}
```

I promise you this will make debugging much much easier

Comment: In the jTable i hava two columns with Date Type ..is that cause any problem ?

Comment: no error but it in the file there is nothin writting :/

Answer (score 0):

Java documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#put-K-V-:

> Returns: the previous value associated with key, or null if there was
>   no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map
>   previously associated null with key.)
>
> NullPointerException - if the specified key is null and this map uses
>   natural ordering, or its comparator does not permit null keys

I have no idea what your trying to put in.. but i would check if you might be putting in a null value.